# When running script for express web server with node on windows get prompt to select app

Tags: node.js, express

I'm going through this [this course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/javascript-development-environment/table-of-contents) currently.

There is a tutorial on how to configure and run `express` server. The following script is suggested:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var open = require('open');

var port = 3000;
var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        open('localhost:'+port);
    }
});
```

When I run it in project root with `$ node buildScripts/srcServer.js` I get a system prompt `You'll need a new app to open this localhost` with the only suggestion being look at windows store.

What's that about? What does it need an app for? In the course when the script is run the browser is opened, but it's on Mac there. When I navigate manually to `localhost:3000` there is the error like there is supposed to be, but I'm somewhat concerned that this behavior will mess with live reloading so I'd like to get rid of it.

Comment: try with `open('http://localhost:'+port);`

Comment: comment `open(....)` line for test and check it on your browser manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the http:// prefix and it will open using the default browser.

`open('http://localhost:'+port);`